# Can low space on a computer negatively effect other devices on the network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

so I have a small network at home of 4 desktops and ~3 WiFi enabled devices. My computer which is connected to the network via WiFi has been running low of hard drive space. This has had the effect of slowing my computer down dramatically which is understandable. One of the side effects seem to be slow download speeds, i.e. taking 8 minutes to download a 450Kb file. I have also experienced slow internet on my other network devices such as my smartphone and desktop connected to the network recently. So I finally decided to delete my 'Downloads' folder and now I have a lot of space again on my PC and it's flying again. The downloads are fast again and all my other devices seems to be able to access the internet faster, i.e. there has been a noticeable streaming speed difference. I would like to know if it is possible that the fact I had low space on my PC could effect the network devices and their network speeds. I am running Windows 7 and my PC is not of importance to the structure of the network, i.e. no bridging is set up etc.

Comment: I think you are just seeing a coincidence. I wouldn't expect running low on hard disk space even to significantly affect download speeds on the local machine.

Comment: Most likely you had a torrent client or such downloading into and uploading from that 'Downloads' directory and when you deleted it all the transfers stopped.

Answer (score 1):

So I realized what the problem was. All my torrents would be downloaded to my 'Downloads' folder and all of the torrents were seeding and that's why the internet connection was so slow. On deleting the folder there were no torrents to seed so the internet connection was no longer hogged.

Comment: Wow, fun times :). ++